# Collatz conjecture in Rust: functional v imperative approach

Tags: optimization, functional-programming, rust

I wanted to play around with some good old [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) and decided that it would be fun to do it in a (very) functional style, so I implemented an `unfoldr` function, close to the one [Haskell has](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr):

```
fn unfoldr<F, T>(foo: F, seed: T, mut vec: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>
    where F: Fn(T) -> Option<(T, T)>
{
    if let Some((x, y)) = foo(seed) {
        vec.push(x);
        unfoldr(foo, y, vec)
    } else {
        vec
    }
}
```

The rest was pretty straightforward:

```
fn collatz_next(n: u64) -> u64 {
    if n % 2 == 0 { n / 2 } else { 3 * n + 1 }
}

pub fn collatz_seq_f(n: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    unfoldr(|n| if n == 1 { None } else { Some((n, collatz_next(n))) }, n, Vec::new())
}
```

With `collatz_seq_f` returning a `Vec`tor with the sequence starting with a given number `n`.

I wondered, however, if Rust approves of this style, and implemented an simple imperative counterpart:

```
pub fn collatz_seq_i(n: u64, mut vec: Vec<u64>) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut c = n;
    while c != 1 {
        vec.push(c);
        c = collatz_next(c);
    }
    vec
}
```

And compared them with `cargo bench` (0.13.0-nightly (2ef3cde 2016-09-04)). I was a bit disappointed that my fun `unfoldr` approach was only half as fast as the imperative implementation:

```
running 3 tests
test tests::it_works ... ignored
test tests::bench_collatz_functional ... bench:         900 ns/iter (+/- 47)
test tests::bench_collatz_imperative ... bench:         455 ns/iter (+/- 29)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 1 ignored; 2 measured
```

I know that the `unfoldr` version is more abstract, but I didn't expect that much of a difference; is there anything that I could change to make it faster?

Full code below:

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

fn unfoldr<F, T>(foo: F, seed: T, mut vec: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>
    where F: Fn(T) -> Option<(T, T)>
{
    if let Some((x, y)) = foo(seed) {
        vec.push(x);
        unfoldr(foo, y, vec)
    } else {
        vec
    }
}

fn collatz_next(n: u64) -> u64 {
    if n % 2 == 0 { n / 2 } else { 3 * n + 1 }
}

pub fn collatz_seq_f(n: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    unfoldr(|n| if n == 1 { None } else { Some((n, collatz_next(n))) }, n, Vec::new())
}

pub fn collatz_seq_i(n: u64, mut vec: Vec<u64>) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut c = n;
    while c != 1 {
        vec.push(c);
        c = collatz_next(c);
    }
    vec
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use test::Bencher;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        assert_eq!(110, collatz_seq_f(27).len());
        assert_eq!(110, collatz_seq_i(27, Vec::new()).len());
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_collatz_functional(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| collatz_seq_f(27));
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_collatz_imperative(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| collatz_seq_i(27, Vec::new()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that since `collatz_next` is very efficient (only a few arithmetic operations), any small overhead becomes non negligible. The boxing due to the option intermediate type could alone bring the performance down. (Just for fun, I'd try using a similar boxing in the imperative version, so to assess its weight)

Comment: By the way, I just tried this in GHC 8 with `-O3`, and as I expected the `Maybe` wrapper was completely removed, turning everything into a simple recursive function using unboxed division, addition, etc.

Comment: @chi: If by "boxing", you mean introducing an indirection through the heap (i.e. storing its contents on the heap), then `Option` in Rust does not do that.

Comment: @FrancisGagné I think he refers to boxed vs unboxed types in Haskell. Unboxed types are represented by their value itself, while boxed one are represented via a pointer to the heap. See for example [ħere](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.3/docs/html/users_guide/primitives.html) (though a bit outdated)

Comment: Current docs regarding unboxed types in Haskell: [GHC 8.0.1 Users Guide](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#unboxed-types-and-primitive-operations)

Comment: @FrancisGagné Yes, I meant having a `Some` object with a reference to a pair, instead of the pair. In Haskell there are additional indirection steps since e.g. an int is actually a null-ary function producing an int (albeit optimization tries to remove this extra step).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is going to contain some implementation details of why `unfoldr` is a bit slow.

I proposed a different variant, and @breeden helped me verify that it is an improvement that makes it match the performance imperative variant. It does preserve the recursion, but we can't call it functional anymore.. [^1]

```
fn unfoldr2<F, T>(foo: F, seed: T, vec: &mut Vec<T>)
    where F: Fn(T) -> Option<(T, T)>
{
    if let Some((x, y)) = foo(seed) {
        vec.push(x);
        unfoldr2(foo, y, vec)
    }
}

fn collatz_next(n: u64) -> u64 {
    if n % 2 == 0 { n / 2 } else { 3 * n + 1 }
}

pub fn collatz_seq_f(n: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    unfoldr2(|n| if n == 1 { None } else { Some((n, collatz_next(n))) }, n, &mut v);
    v
}
```

The difference here will illustrate what “went wrong” with the first version. In `unfoldr`, there is a vec value being carried around, and in `unfoldr2` there is just a mutable reference to a vector instead.

The vec value has an effect in `unfoldr` and you discovered it limited the compiler: unwinding. Unwinding is what happens if a function panics. If it unwinds through the `unfoldr` function, all local variables must be dropped, and that means `vec`. Some special code is inserted to deal with this (called a “landing pad”) and function calls that may panic insert an instruction to divert to the landing pad on panic.

So in `unfoldr`:

1. There's a local variable that has a destructor, `vec`
2. There's a function call that may panic (`vec.push` panics on capacity overflow)
3. There's a landing pad that drops `vec` and resumes unwinding

Additionally, there's code to move the Vec value around. (It is copied to the stack to be available for the landing pad code).

`unfoldr2` doesn't get any magic recursion-into-just-a-loop optimization or so, but it still has less code because it has no need to handle unwinding or move the Vec.

[^1]: Can we salvage the functional-ness by imagining the vec.push(x) as being an interface to a stream / generator / outputiterator, or just be a callback?

Comment: I'm not bent on having a functional implementation - I just remembered having implemented it in Haskell this way and wanted to try the same approach in Rust. Of course it's not exactly the Rust-y way, but I wanted to know the reason behind the difference in performance. Unwinding seems to be the answer.

Comment: I think it's a common issue with C++ as well: landing pads/destructors prevent tail-recursion from kicking in, which is a problem GC'ed languages do not have.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, but an additional test to narrow down where the performance hit is coming from.  I unrolled the `Some` overhead by writing the recursive function

```
pub fn collatz_seq_r(n: u64, mut vec: Vec<u64>) -> Vec<u64> {
    if n == 1 {
        vec
    } else {
        vec.push(n);
        collatz_seq_r(collatz_next(n), vec)
    } 
}
```

I obtained nearly identical performance as with the `collatz_seq_f` example.  It appears that LLVM is not unrolling this recursive call.

### Alternative

After thinking about how I would do this in Rust, I would most likely have implemented an iterator whose job is to continuously compose the previous value with a function, providing a non-terminating sequection: `n, f(n), f(f(n)), ..., f^k(n), ...`.  This can be done like this:

```
struct Compose<T, F> {
    value: T,
    func: F
}

impl<T, F> Iterator for Compose<T, F> 
    where T: Copy,
          F: Fn(T) -> T {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let res = self.value;                    // f^k(n)
        self.value = (self.func)(self.value);    // f^{k+1}(n)
        Some(res)
    }
}

impl<T, F> Compose<T, F> {
    fn new(seed: T, func: F) -> Compose<T, F> {
        Compose { 
            value: seed,
            func: func
        }
    }
}
```

So here I can call `Compose::new(seed_value, function)` to get an iterator of composition.  Generating the a Collatz sequence then becomes:

```
pub fn collatz_seq_iter(n: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    Compose::new(n, collatz_next)
             .take_while(|&n| n != 1)
             .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}
```

With this I get the benchmarks:

```
test tests::bench_collatz_functional ... bench:         867 ns/iter (+/- 28)
test tests::bench_collatz_imperative ... bench:         374 ns/iter (+/- 9)
test tests::bench_collatz_iterators  ... bench:         473 ns/iter (+/- 9)
test tests::bench_collatz_recursive  ... bench:         838 ns/iter (+/- 29)
```

But the interesting thing here is, if you decide that you only care about the size after all, the call: `Compose::new(n, collatz_next).take_while(|&n| n != 1).count() as u64` has almost exactly the same performance as removing the `vec.push(c)` line in the imperative approach:

```
test tests::bench_collatz_imperative ... bench:         162 ns/iter (+/- 6)
test tests::bench_collatz_iterators  ... bench:         163 ns/iter (+/- 4)
```

Comment: I like the iterator approach - it looks like the proper way to do it.

Comment: I experimented a bit with your implementation and I just have 2 suggestions: the `new` method doesn't require a `where` clause (I guess it is inherited) and `F` can just be `Fn(T)`.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking other people on IRC to make suggestions.  You were the first :) I'll update it now.  Also, apparently I don't need the `where` clause at all for `impl<T, F> Compose<T, F>`.